# C's scanf function. If a width modifier is use, Eg: %5d. How to prevent any excess number type in by user from being read into the next %d specifier?

Tags: c, scanf

I would like the user to key in 2 numbers and use `scanf` function to read in these two numbers into 2 `int` variables.

```
int num, num2;

scanf("%5d %d", &num, &num2);
printf("num = %d\n", num);
printf("num2 = %d\n", num2);
```

If the user key in the first number with the number of digits greater than 5, any excess digits should be discarded.

Eg: If user enters the following at the prompt

```
% 12345678 222<Enter>
num = 12345
num2 = 678
```

What I want is:

```
num = 12345
num2 = 222
```

I have modified my `scanf` function pattern to the following:

```
scanf("%5d %*[0123456789] %d", &num, &num2 );
```

This seems to solve the problem, if the first number that the user input in more than 5 digit, but if it is 5 digit or less, this format specifier will discard the second number that the user key in, and a third number need to be key in.

Eg: If the user key the following in the command prompt:

```
% 12345 222 333 <Enter>
num = 12345
num2 = 333
```

What I want is:

```
num = 12345
num2 = 222
```

Any C professional out there can offer a solution, thanks.

Comment: Why can't you just test the value received and truncate it? Test if the value is greater  than 99999 (5 digits) and if so, convert it to a string and keep just the first 5 digits in the string and convert that back to a integer. You might be able to do it mathematically too.

Comment: Read and discard a character at a time until a whitespace (Or whatever) character is encountered.

Comment: Alternatively, read in a whole line, then pick it apart at leisure with `strtol`, `strchr` et al.; generally speaking you shouldn't use `*scanf()` on user input at all (as its capabilities to tell you what exactly went wrong at which point of malformed input are limited). Use `*scanf()` on known well-formatted data only (such as data your application itself has written earlier via `*printf()`).

Comment: @AndrewTruckle ,yes, i know there is many ways to achieve the end result, I'm just figuring out if there is any pattern of format specifier of the scanf function, that can solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the space **before** the scanset and also that the scanset must match to move to the next field. Try this:

```
scanf("%5d%*[0123456789]", &num);
scanf("%d", &num2);
```

2 scanf invocations are required because the scanset will *not* match if the first number is 5 digits or less.

(And you must check the return values of both)

Comment: @jason with 2 scanf invocations?

Comment: Hi Antti, after reading more deeply about your comment, got it now, thanks heaps :)

Comment: But note that any use of `%d` without a maximum width is liable to be undefined behavior, if scanf attempts to match a string that does not fit in an int.  (eg, if INT_MAX is 2147483647 and the input string is 3147483647)

Answer (score 0):

The goal here strikes me as questionable. Silently ignoring user input, even if you consider it incorrect, is highly confusing for the user and can end up compounding errors.

Anyway, you're not going to be able to do that with a single call to `scanf`. So you need to do it pieces: use `scanf` to read at most five characters as an integer. Then `getc` the next character; if it's a digit (see `isdigit()`), discard it and repeat. Finally, `scanf` the second integer.

Comment: You can use a scanset for that

Comment: @antti: yes, you can, but if you do it my way you get better diagnostic options.